# Putting private files in Dropbox

Tags: android

I want to have m user the ability to upload/download the sql lite db to/from DropBox.

The only problem is that the files are in internal storage. How can I have DropBox read/write access to them?

The only way I can think of is copying it to SD card, then to dropbox and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [FileProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to identify a directory where files can be shared (see link for instructions). Then use [FileProvider.getUriForFile(Context, String, File)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#getUriForFile%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29) to construct the `Uri`.

Alternatively, use [Context.grantUriPermission(String, Uri, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#grantUriPermission%28java.lang.String,%20android.net.Uri,%20int%29), if you are already using a `ContentProvider`.

Comment: Thank you . Iwill check it. Is only applicable for reading? What about writing (say I want to replace the internal file with the one in drop box)?

Comment: So there is no way I can write to internal from dropbox?

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong. FileProver can be used for both, and so can  `Context.grantUriPermission(String, Uri, int)` using flag `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION`. TIL.